# adb doesn't recognize Samsung Note II and Note 10.1

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile

Is there something special I have to do to get adb to recognize my phone and tablet?

I turned on developer mode, but when I do "adb devices" I still only get the emulator or nothing at all if there's no emulator running.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your development machine's operating system? If Windows, did you install the Samsung `adb` drivers?

Comment: It is Windows. Oh, I probably didn't then unless those are included with the USB drivers?

Comment: where can I find the drivers? I can't find it on the Samsung website. thanks! =]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: oh, I already installed that driver and `adb devices` still doesn't recognize my device. There's no software on Samsung to download either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Google'd a bit more and found that if you install Samsung Kies then adb starts recognizing Samsung products. =]

Answer (score 7):

In case you are working under Windows, try to install [Samsung USB Driver for Windows](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows) .. it should be enough ;-)